# convert while to comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a `while` loop that generates numbers between 1-10, 10 times:

```
n=0
while n < 11:
    n=n+1
    num = random.randint(1,10)
    print(num)
```

I want to convert this into a python3 comprehension in a single statement.

how can I do so?

Comment: I don't see a _list_ anywhere. Why exactly would you like to turn this into a list comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This list comprehension saves all the random ints to a list called `ranNums`

```
ranNums = [random.randint(1,10) for  i in range(11)]
print(ranNums)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Im not sure why people are downvoting you. Ill accept when I can.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Downvoting a perfectly good answer calls for more upvotes: the opposite effect. Aside: `i` could be `_` because it's not used.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, any performance gain say if max was a huge number or just matter of better convention?

Comment: With range(11) the list has 11 elements, not 10. But I'm not sure if this is what the @Jshee wants or if the `while n < 11` was a mistake.

Comment: @UpSampler - yea, changed to 10, typo on my end - thanks

Comment: no performance gain, just clearer that you don't use the loop index.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: If you have the latest version of Python, you don't need to to do this

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a list comprehension for procedural calls as it generates a wasteful list of `None`.

However, if you do actually want to store the results (and not just `print` them), then upgrade to Python 3.6 and you can use `random.choices`:

```
import random
random.choices(range(11),k=11)
```

This is like `random.sample` but with replacement.